# Pascal multiple records being passed into a function

Tags: pascal

This is my code:

```
 type
  TStudent = record
    Firstname:string[15];
    Surname:string[15];
    dateofbirth:tdatetime;
    gender: char;
    ASmark: integer;
  end;


var student: array [1..10] of tstudent;
    option:integer;
```

...

```
function readrecord:tstudent;
var //dob:string;
    i:integer;
begin
   for i := 1 to 10 do
   begin
    Writeln('Enter Firstname for student ',i, ' : ');
    readln(student[i].firstname);
    Writeln('Enter Surname ',i, ' : ');
    readln(student[i].Surname);
    writeln('Enter Date of Birth ',i, ' : ');
    //readln(dob);
    //student[i].dateofbirth:=strtodate(dob);
    Writeln('Enter Gender (M or F) ',i, ' : ');
    readln(student[i].gender);
    Writeln('Enter AS Mark ',i, ' : ');
    readln(student[i].ASmark);
   end;
end;
```

DOB is commented out for now, don't worry about that :)

```
procedure averagemark(var student:tstudent);

var mark:real;i:integer;
begin
   mark:=0;
   for  i := 1 to 10 do
   begin
   mark:=mark+(student[i].asmark);
   end;
   mark:=(mark/10);
   writeln('Average mark: ',mark:5:2);



end;
```

I am trying to get an average of the `asmark`, but I get errors for `mark:=mark+(student[i].asmark);` which are `Error: no default property available` and `Fatal: Syntax error,")" expected but "[" found`.

It would be much appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction as I have tried quite a lot of things and also researched.

I also created a data type called `tstudenta` which was an array of the `tstudent` record, then set `student:tstudentr;` but had no luck here either.

Comment: What Pascal compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure averagemark(var student: tstudent);
```

You pass a single record here instead of an array. Use an open array:

```
procedure averagemark(const students: array of tstudent);
```

Loop from `low(students)` to `high(students)` rather than hard coding the array bounds.

If your Pascal dialect does not support open arrays, then you should use an array. If it suffices to use an array with a fixed length of 10 then you could define the array type like so:

```
type
  TStudentArray = array [1..10] of TStudent;
```

You'd then use that type for the parameter of your procedure:

```
procedure averagemark(const students: TStudentArray);
```

It's a little tricky to be specific without more knowledge of your particular Pascal dialect. However, the essence is as I have said. You need to pass an array of records rather than a single record.

Comment: (aren't open arrays a Delphi feature? Afaik TP doesn't, OP should post dialect)

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort I'm not sure. I added some more to the answer. As you say, it's tricky to be specific without knowing what language features are available.